# Watir How to get rows with different classes

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I need to get all rows with class named 'odd_row' or 'even_row'.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="first_row"> … </tr>
    <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"> … </tr>
    <tr class="odd_row"> … </tr>
    <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"> … </tr>
    <tr class="even_row"> … </tr>
    <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"> … </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried this:

```
@b.table(:class => 'color_table').tbody.trs(:class => ('odd_row' || 'even_row').size
```

But it returns 1.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do an "or" of classes, you need to use a regular expression. In regular expressions, "or" is done using a single pipe character "|". The class locator you would want is:

```
:class => /odd_row|even_row/
```

Therefore, to count all odd and even rows, you want:

```
@b.table(:class => 'color_table')
  .tbody
  .trs(:class => /odd_row|even_row/)
  .size
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.size` at the end. This gets the size of the array as an integer. You can try without it.

Comment: I tried like this too but it still returns 1:

    sub = 0
    @b.table(:class => 'color_table').tbody.trs(:class =>
    ('odd_row'|| 'even_row').find do |tr|
        sub = sub + 1
    end
    return sub

Comment: You can try searching like this: `:class => ['odd_row', 'even_row']`

Comment: It gives an error:  expected one of [String, Regexp], got ["odd_row", "even_row"]:Array

Comment: Hmm, you can pass a Regexp then. Something like `/.*_row/`. This would match `odd_row` and `even_row`.