# How to find elements using several conditions in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

There is a table which rows are with different class names: first_row, odd_row, even_row and subjectField.

HTML:

```
<table class="color_table">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="first_row"></tr>
          <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
          <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
          <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
          <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
            **63**
          </td>
        <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"></tr>
        <tr class="odd_row"></tr>
        <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"></tr>
        <tr class="even_row"></tr>
        <tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"></tr>
    </tbody>
```

Additional HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="first_row"></tr>
<tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"></tr>
<tr class="odd_row"></tr>
<tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="separator" rowspan="1" colspan="10"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even_row"></tr>
<tr class="subjectField" style="display:none"></tr>

</tbody>
```

I need to get information from all rows except row which class name is 'subjectField'

My code:

```
table = @f.div(:id => 'household').table(:class => 'color_table')
table.tbody.trs(:class => 'first_row', :class => 'odd_row', :class =>'even_row').each do
    age = tr.td(:index => 3).text
puts age
end
```

This code takes all rows, subjectFields rows too.
Does anybody know how to make it work with the rows I need only?

Comment: Does the approach in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610984/watir-how-to-get-rows-with-different-classes) not work? Other than the addition of wanting to include the 'first_row', this seems like the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To find everything except a class, use a regex with a negative lookahead:

```
table.trs(:class => /^(?!subjectField)/).size
```

If you want to get the text for each of these rows:

```
puts table.trs(:class => /^(?!subjectField)/).collect(&:text)
```

If you want to get the text of the fourth column for each cell:

```
puts table.trs(:class => /^(?!subjectField)/).collect do |row|
   row.td(:index => 3).text
end
```

Comment: I changed the description a bit. Should this work:
    `table.tbody.trs(:class => /^(!?subjectField)$/).each do |tr|
 age = tr.td(:index => 3).text
        puts age
    end`

Comment: The general concept works regardless of whatever you want to do with the collection of rows. I added the examples for getting text of the matching rows.

Comment: I can't understand why but it does not get the right number. Every time it prints '0'

Comment: It works for me given the html supplied. My guess is that your actual html is different than the sample you have given - for example, is there a row with class subjectField and something else? In that case, yes the code would have to be different.

Comment: I added additional code. Can this separator class be the problem? For this separator I have this in my code:

`if tr.td(:class => "separator").exists? == true
    break 
else
 puts tr.td(:index => 3).text
end
`

Comment: I get 4 rows for the second table you gave, so the code seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

it is really simple:

```
table = @f.div(:id => 'household').table(:class => 'color_table')

table_element.count #it will display the count of all rows corresponding to specified table.

table_elements(:class => 'first row').index #will return the array count [0]
table_elements(:class => 'even_row').index #will return the array count [2]
```

Comment: Actually I don't need to count the rows, I need to use these rows in getting the specific text from them.

Comment: Are you sure this code will work? I do not believe there is a `table_element` or `table_elements` method in Watir.

Answer (score 0):

not a problem actually

```
table_elements(:class => 'first row').text # if you need to take the text from the row with corresponding class
```

or

```
table_elements[0].text
```

Comment: You should probably edit your existing answer rather than create a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this

```
...(:xpath, "//table/tbody/tr[@class !='subjectField']")...
```

Comment: One of the reasons to use Watir at all is so that you never have to use xpath to identify an element.